# Sharp's Exercise 16.37

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am reading Sharp's book "Steps in Commutative Algebra".

But I really had difficulty in the exercise below. So can you give me a hint about the exercise below?

> **Exercise 16.37**
>   Let $R$ denote the ring of polynomials $\mathbb{Z}_{2\mathbb{Z}}[X]$
>   in the indeterminate $X$ over the local ring $\mathbb{Z}_{2\mathbb{Z}}$.
>   Use the natural injective ring homomorphism
>   $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_{2\mathbb{Z}}$ to identity elements
>   of $\mathbb{Z}$ as elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{2\mathbb{Z}}$. Show that
>   $2$, $X$ form an $R$-sequence which is maximal (in the sense that it
>   cannot be extended to a longer $R$-sequence), and that the single
>   element $1-2X$ also forms a maximal $R$-sequence.

Comment: Sharp says "indeterminate". Now, which step is causing you difficulty: (i) is $2,X$ and $R$-sequence (ii) its a **maximal** $R$-sequence, (iii) $1-2X$ is an $R$-sequence, (iv) it's a **maximal** $R$-sequence?

Comment: You alright. I had difficulty in steps (i) and (iii). I find it difficult to show that they are R-sequences.

Answer (score 1):

I don't much like Sharp's notation. What we have here is $R=S[X]$ where
$S$ is the ring of rationals with odd denominators (that is what $\Bbb Z_{2\Bbb Z}$
is in Sharp's baroque notation). Anyway $R$ is an integral domain. Integral
domains have no zero divisors, so $a\in R$ forms an $R$-sequence of length $1$
iff $a\ne 0$ and $aR\ne R$, that is $a$ is non-zero and a non-unit.
So $2$ forms an $R$-sequence and $1-2X$ forms an $R$-sequence as neither are
units in $R$.

Now $R/2R\cong\Bbb F_2[X]$ is a polynomial ring over $\Bbb F_2$
(since $S/2S\cong\Bbb F_2$). Then $X$ is a non-zero non-unit in this ring.
This means that $2,X$ forms an $R$-sequence.

To show these sequences are maximal, we need to consider the $R$-modules
$R/(2R+XR)$ and $R/(1-2X)R$ and show these are simple modules. As they
are rings too, all we need is to prove they are fields. I'll leave
this as an "exercise for the reader".

Overall, this is a nice example, showing that even in very "tame" rings
there can be maximal $R$-sequences of different lengths.

Comment: Okay! Thanks to your comment, I get it. Thanks.